# Argument isn't numeric - question

Tags: perl, warnings, number-formatting

Why doesn't the first example output a warning?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;

my $c = "9\n";
say $c * 2;

my $d = "6a";
say $d * 2;

# 18
# Argument "6a" isn't numeric in multiplication (*) at ./perl8.pl line 9.
# 12
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When converting a number from a string, trailing whitespace is ignored, and newline counts as whitespace, so a warning isn't generated. Converting "9 " doesn't generate a warning either.

Answer (score 1):

Because Perl thinks it's a number:

```
use Scalar::Util 'looks_like_number';

for ("9\n", "6a") {
    say looks_like_number($_);
}

1
0
```